# Why did the writer write "give me back my earrings" there?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain why it's there? Does it mean anything to the paragraph? I don't find it was what the reporter said when he ghosted her.

"Although she wrote glowingly of her unnamed platonic “dates” with LinkedIn scientists and entrepreneurs – nearly all with partnered men who were kind and strictly professional with their career advice – she hinted at a tryst with a reporter who then “ghosted” her (“give me back my earrings, [expletive]!”). She didn’t name the reporter, but in a spiteful turn, sprinkled in enough details for his friends and colleagues to identify him. That’s not the kind of professional attention anyone ever wants to attract."

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/dianahembree/2017/07/30/linkedin-is-not-a-dating-site/#6eab19d54e89

Comment: She left her earrings by the bedside?  The reporter treats her as if she no longer exists and does not respond to communications from her.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Tᴚoɯɐuo points out, it probably means she left her errings when she left in the morning. The hint is in "*a tryst with a reporter*".

> **tryst** - a private, romantic rendezvous between lovers.

"who then *ghosted* her"

> **ghosting** - the practice of ending a personal relationship with someone by suddenly and without explanation withdrawing from all communication.

So she is, in a very public way  asking for her earrings back.
Men usually will return earrings, knickers are a different story...

Comment: -1 for the comma splice

Comment: Is that where we get the verb **to knick**?